# React Framer Motion in-between color transition

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm using `framer-motion` to animate an `Icon` component when hovered as follow :

```
<Icon
    initial={{ scale: 1, color: "#B9BBBE" }}
    whileHover={{
        scale: 1.15,
        color: "#FFCC4D",
    }}
    transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 500 }}
>
    <Emoji />
</Icon>
```

The `Icon` contains a simple SVG `Emoji` with a grey color `#B9BBBE`, and I also use this color in the `initial` prop.

I need the transition to go from that to the yellow `#FFCC4D`, but when I move out of the icon, it transitions back from the yellow to a shade of blue and then the initial grey color.

I can't figure out how to transition from yellow directly to the grey, without any weird colors in between.

I also tried to pass an array as follow, but still got the same result :

```
whileHover={{
    scale: 1.15,
    color: ["#B9BBBE", "#FFCC4D"],
}}
```

Comment: Can you make reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/? I've tried with div and it works fine at first glance https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69700767-246lb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Danila Thanks for the reply, it isn't very apparent in this square div example, but when you moveout of the div the color transition is going through the color wheel till it ends up in the initial grey, you can also see that when you inspect the element's css, you see the css rgb property going through the numbers & I guess that is the cause, but I have no idea how to avoid it..

Comment: This is a Gif I recorded of how I my icon behaves : https://imgur.com/a/izweAcA, you can clearly see that blueish transition before it ends up in the initial grey.

Comment: @Danila Oh in fact, the `transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 500 }}` is the cause of this : https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69700767-forked-czkz4?file=/src/App.js You can now see the div turning blue clearly. If you have any idea why is that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess stiffness creates this color "bounce":

> A spring’s Stiffness determines the spring's velocity and how many times the spring will bounce before the spring settles and the animation ends.

So you need apply spring and stiffness only for `scale` property for bounce effect, and leave color as is:

```
      <motion.div
        style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
        initial={{ scale: 1, backgroundColor: '#B9BBBE' }}
        whileHover={{
          scale: 1.15,
          backgroundColor: '#FFCC4D'
        }}
        transition={{ scale: { type: 'spring', stiffness: 500 } }}
      ></motion.div>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69700767-forked-bk5v6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You're right, thank you!